# PHPs Doctrine creates empty records

Tags: php, doctrine

I played a lot with Doctrine 1.2. Creating and deleting records are no problem anymore ;). But sometimes i have empty records in my database. Every field is set to NULL. I have the feeling it has something to do with relations. How can i prevent Doctrine of creating such empty entries.

Comment: First you need to locate the exact problem. Post your code or do something to debug it and locate the place, where empty records appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema use the tag notnull: true   to force non-empty fields
and use primary: true  for id's
i.e.:

```
table:
  columns:
    id:
      primary: true
      unsigned: true
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
    field:
      type: ...
      notnull: true
```

I this does not help you, please put further information

Answer (score 0):

This should be a Problem in Code, Doctrine itself does not create empty records. I believe you save somewhere a null filled model.

Be carefull with `notnull:true` as it leads to incompatibilities with Oracle, if you don't solve above Problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have only found this somewhat hackish solution so far, to be inserted for each related field for which a null values should be possible.

```
public function preSave($trigger) {

  // Avoid empty relations
  if(!$this->getRelatedobjectId())
    $this->setRelatedobject(null);
  }
}
```